# Class taking in instance as argument

Tags: python

I have the following class:

```
class Optimization_problem():
    def __init__(self, **args):
        if 'function' in args:  
            self.function = args['function']
        if 'gradient' in args:  
            self.gradient = args['gradient']
        else:
            def deriv(x):
                return nd.Gradient(self.function)(x)
            self.gradient= deriv

        if 'acc' in args:  
            self.acc = args['acc']
```

I want to create a class `Optmization_method` which inherits the attributes from the class above in such a way that i can do the following:

```
f = lambda x: 100 * (x[1] - x[0] ** 2) ** 2 + (1 - x[0]) ** 2
problem = Optimization_problem(function=f, acc=1.e-3)
method = Optimization_method(problem) # I want to be able to do this
```

I have tried the following but it doesn't work.

```
class Optimization_method(Optimization_problem):    
    def __init__(self, **args):
        Optimization_problem.__init__(self, **args)

    #methods......
```

Comment: Do always include what happens instead, when something *doesn't work*, with full tracebacks.

Comment: Why does `method` derive from `problem` instead of having a `problem` as a member variable? In other words, this seems like a Composition vs Inheritance problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are just passing in a simple single argument. If you want to *copy* attributes across, you'd have to specifically look for such an instance and copy out the data you want. That can be as simple as copying the `__dict__` mapping:

```
if len(args) == 1 and isinstance(args[0], Optimization_problem):
    self.__dict__.update(args[0].__dict__)
    return
```

Note that this has nothing to do with inheritance; inheritance doesn't give you the ability to copy state (data) from a base class, it gives you the ability to reuse and extend *functionality*.

If you wanted to reuse the attributes of a specific instance, just *store a reference to instance*, a concept called *composition*:

```
class Optimization_method:    
    def __init__(self, problem):
        self.problem = problem

    def method1(self,x):
        return self.problem.function(x)
```

Only use inheritance if you want `Optimization_method` instances to support the same operations as `Optimization_problem`. Use composition if you want to be able to reference the state and functionality of another instance for what the current class needs to achieve.